Deleted emojis are recognized as already existing
I created a function to add emojis using discord.js. Already added emojis are not added, but even if delete the emoji and run it again, it is recognized as already existing.
let emoji_image_url = 'https://cdn.theatlantic.com/thumbor/HSNOivXdm_GB-_tJqqq-Jh-T8SY=/312x304:3688x3680/540x540/media/img/mt/2017/08/shutterstock_668917297/original.jpg';
let emoji_id = 'test_emoji';
const existingEmoji = interaction.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === emoji_id);
if (!existingEmoji) {
    await interaction.guild.emojis.create({ attachment: `${emoji_image_url}`, name: `${emoji_id}` });
} else {
    console.log(`'${emoji_id}' is already exists`);
}

Already added emoticons are not added, but if you delete the already added emoticon and run the command again, it will be recognized as an already added emoticon.

There's no question here.
